# Using ACS as a service with custom identity provider

Tags: authentication, service, identity, provider, acs

We are working in an iOS application and we use back-end in azure. We have 2 types of login, one is Facebook login (using Fb as identity provider) and the other will be login directly to our system.
 We decided to use ACS but we had a bunch of technical problems. My question is is it possible to create custom identity provider, which will be a service (for example WCF or WEB API) to generate a token that we pass the ACS to get the claim token. Does ACS support that kind of service interface? If so what what is the practice of generating tokens in our custom identity provider?

Thanks in advance,
Deuce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACS can support any identity provider that speaks a protocol it understands. Depending on the backend behind your identity provider, you can use something like ADFS or write your own identity provider using WIF. ACS doesn't support mixing and matching web-based identity providers with WCF-based ones, which means that you'll need to expose a website that ACS can redirect a browser to using the WS-Federation protocol. The only external contract you have is that ACS will redirect users to you and you need to log them in (what that means for your IdP is up to you) and issue a token back to ACS.

There are literally whole books on how to write your own STS using WIF, to get started there are a number of resources that can help, including the [WIF SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4451) (which provides a template for the STS), [this whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/D/0/7D0B5166-6A8A-418A-ADDD-95EE9B046994/WindowsIdentityFoundation-WhitepaperForDevelopers-RC.pdf) (see the section "Using Windows Identity Foundation to Build a Security Token Service"), or [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2008/11/26/an-identity-provider-and-its-sts-writing-a-custom-sts-with-the-october-beta-of-the-geneva-framework.aspx).